# Plotting of coordinates in R

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I have a number of coordinates and I want to plot them in a gridded interface by using R.
The problem is that the relative distance between observations is large. Coordinates are in a geographic coordinate system and the study area is Switzerland. Moreover, id of the points is required to be plotted.

The problem is that two clusters of the points are dense and some other points are separated with a large distance. How I can plot them in a proper way to have readable presentation? Any suggestion for plotting the data?

Preferably, do not use `ggplot` as I used it before and it did not present proper results.

Data:

```
id x y
2 7.1735 45.86880001
3 7.17254 45.86887001
4 7.171636 45.86923601
5 7.18018 45.87158001
6 7.17807 45.87014001
7 7.177229 45.86923001
8 7.17524 45.86808001
9 7.181409 45.87177001
10 7.179299 45.87020001
11 7.178359 45.87070001
12 7.175189 45.86974001
13 7.179379 45.87081001
14 7.175509 45.86932001
15 7.176839 45.86939001
17 7.18099 45.87262001
18 7.18015 45.87248001
19 7.18122 45.87355001
20 7.17491 45.86922001
25 7.15497 45.87058001
28 7.153399 45.86954001
29 7.152649 45.86992001
31 7.154419 45.87004001
32 7.156099 45.86983001
GSBi_1 7.184 45.896
GSBi__1 7.36 45.901
GSBj__1 7.268 45.961
GSBj_1 7.276 45.836
GSB 7.272 45.899
GSB_r 7.166667 45.866667
```

Location of points:

[image]

As you can see in the plot, the points' ids are not readable both for the dense parts and others.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're really asking but it sounds like you want to set the _range_ of the axes of your plot?

Comment: @mostar, plotting the data.

Comment: @JackAidley, it cannot help because two cluster of points are realy close to each other and 6 other points are far.

Comment: of course it is clear that you want to plot some data. but do you want to learn how to code it with R, or how to display close points clearly without overlapping while there are far points in the same graph, or anything different? i mean what's your real problem?

Comment: @mostar I exactually want to 'display close points clearly without overlapping while there are far points in the same graph' possibly with guidance on codeing in R.

Comment: @HamedFootohi - you need to be *really specific* when asking S.O. questions. I would suggest editing your question to add the info you have just commented, but with more detail about *exactly* what sort of issues you want addressed.

Comment: I think he's suggesting some sort of non-linear scale which spreads out the aesthetic distance between close points while holding the distance between the farther points constant. Instead, I would just recommend two plots--one showing the full view and another zoomed in on the cluster.

Comment: @Hamed: Thank you, your question is clearer now. I agree with Michael; the best approach is two plots.

Comment: You might think about setting the scale to be non-linear. Perhaps a log-scale or a sqrt-scale would make the plot more distinguishable. It depends on what story you want to tell with the plot.

In this case, I agree with the rest however: two plots might make a bit more sense.

Comment: I would go with a log scale as well.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, it is not always possible to ensure that all points are visually separable on the screen when plotting a set of points that contains very close and very far points at the same time.

Think of a 1000x800 pixel screen. Let's say we have three points A, B and C that are located respectively on the same horizontal line such that: the distance between A and B is 1 unit and the distance between A and C is 4000 unit.

If you map this maximum distance (4000 unit) to the width of the screen (1000px). Then a pixel will correspond to 4 units in horizontal. That means A and B will fit into one pixel since the distance between them is only 1 unit. So, they will not be visually separable on the screen.

Comment: and this means you should have multiple views or zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Your points are far too close to really do too much with, but an idea might be `spread.labels` from plotrix:

```
opar <- par()
par(xpd=TRUE)

plot(dat$x, dat$y)
spread.labels(dat$x,dat$y,dat$id)

par(opar)
```

[image]

You may want to consider omitting all the numerical labels and placing them in a different graph.

Comment: Can you please assist me in how to locate only the minimum point coordinates in multiple lines r graph, for example, if the minimum coordinates is (17, 2.333), how to locate in r graph this point only? I would appreciate for your assistance.

Comment: Can you give me the syntax? or how can I mark the lowest point and may put it in the legend?

Comment: If we're at a point where you're asking for syntax, you should ask a question on the site normally. That way other people can more easily benefit from the answer and we're not restricted by the limits of a comment section.